# html mouseover event on element border

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering whether it is possible to bind mouseover event to one of the HTML element border, say, the left border of a div.

The div is a container for other complex html elements, and there are mouseover events attached for its sub elements. Binding mouseover event to the whole container div itself is a method, however the user will not be able to distinguish whether he select the container or the sub elements.

I want a very obvious method to indicate that the container can be selected, like highlighting the container when he mouseover the left border area.

Or is there any other good way to solve the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: what do u mean?? bind a the border of a div with events..?

Comment: Why not simply change the colour, or style, of the border or cursor on mouseover?

Comment: Hi David, What I want is to highlight left border when user mouseover left border area of the div, but not when user mouseover the whole div.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Borders are not elements, and as such you cannot bind mouseenter events to them. If you wanted this type of functionality, you would need to place a series of elements around the edges of the element (or at least next to your target edge), and bind to that.

This particular approach was taken by Dropbox in their web-based upload feature. When you drag a file from your desktop onto their page, you'll notice that `div` elements around the top, bottom, and sides all fade into view. This was accomplished with four `div` elements placed near the edges of the viewport.

Comment: Agree with Jonathan. I didn't use Dropbox, I am actually doing something a little bit look like FB timeline, where the timeline itself can be highlighted when mouseover it.

Answer (score 2):

do you want like this

http://jsfiddle.net/GBpcg/

**EDIT :** http://jsfiddle.net/GBpcg/2/

Comment: Thank you Pravallika69. What I want is to highlight left border when user mouseover left border area of the div, not when user mouseover the whole div.

Comment: Thank you Pravallika69, that is similar to what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @Pravallika69 You shouldn't be using the same id over and over. Use a class instead. The id attribute is meant to contain a unique value to the document whereas the class attribute can contain general, and repeated, values.